# Where can I get the F# Compiler and FSI v4.0?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I know I can download the "April CTP" to get F# 2.0 for .NET 2.0. But I need FSC and F# Interactive for .NET 4.0. On a machine with VS 2010 installed, it ends up in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft F#\v4.0. Is there a redistributable for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Others have provided good answers; I'll summarize and add one more bit (2nd bullet):

- We don't have any polished story here yet.  We're working on one.
- In the case of the compiler, you may be able to get by with the fsc.exe in the April CTP (it is capable of referencing .NET 4.0 assemblies and building .NET 4.0 assemblies, even though the compiler itself runs on 2.0).  (Note that for building project files, you might also need the right Microsoft.FSharp.targets imported; I haven't worked all that through...)
- If you were to copy the right assemblies and targets files from a VS2010 install to another machine, that would work, but offhand I don't know if that violates the VS license.
- The existing downloadable "redist" does only contain FSharp.Core.dll.

(possibly see also [this](http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/13858.aspx) for a similar discussion but no extra info, as well as [this Connect request](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/550454/f-in-express-or-integrated-shell-modes))

Answer (score 19):

If you installed *Visual Studio 11 Beta* or *Visual Studio 2012*, I recommend you check the following path, where you will find `Fsi.exe` and `Fsc.exe`.

> ```
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.0\Framework\v4.0
> ```

Comment: I have installed Visual Studio 2012, and this is the path to Fsi.exe. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The redistributable, for the F# runtime, is available at the following link, but unfortunately doesn't include the compiler or F# interactive:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=5f0a79f8-925f-4297-9ae2-86e2fdcff33c&displaylang=en

If you already have VS2010 installed on the machine there shouldn't be no need to install it, as the compiler, fsi, and F# runtime will be installed with VS. It should be just a matter of adding the directory containing the compiler to the path, so the shell can find it (if you want to use the compiler/fsc from the command-line).

Comment: Does the redistributable include fsi and fsc? The page does not mention them.

Comment: I have just tried on my test machine - it does not. It is pure runtime support for F# assemblies only, not scripts.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but I came across it and thought that I'd add an update for people who find it through Google:

The current version of the F# CTP ([April 2011](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11100)) includes both .NET 2.0 and .NET 4.0 binaries, including FSI.exe. On my install...

```
.NET 2 = C:\Program Files (x86)\FSharp-2.0.0.0\bin\
.NET 4 = C:\Program Files (x86)\FSharp-2.0.0.0\v4.0\bin\
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that there is no standalone installation of F# for .NET 4.0 (similar to the standalone installation for .NET 2.0). The reason probably is that F# for .NET 4.0 is simply meant to be distributed only as part of Visual Studio 2010 and not separately (just like other core Visual Studio languages).

If you need to use `fsi.exe` and `fsc.exe` for .NET 4.0 on a machine that doesn't have Visual Studio installed, you'll probably need to copy them together with the referenced libraries. This shouldn't be that difficult - you only need assemblies from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft F#\v4.0" together with `FSharp.Core.dll` (which should be added to the GAC) and (I think) also `ISymWrapper.dll` (but I'm not quite sure where this is located).

Comment: I suspect it might be against the EULA to copy parts of Visual Studio 2010 to machines for which one does not have VS 2010 licenses. I haven't checked though.

Comment: I had a sinking feeling that was the case :(. Well, if they actually do release it under the MS-Pl, then perhaps someone can setup a CodePlex project to make a nice redist for them.

Comment: @MichaelGG: As far as I know, there are still plans to do that (It makes sense that it's taking so long - the team was surely busy finishing F# for Visual Studio 2010).